# Accessing IIS 7.5 Express from another machine on the intranet

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5, iis-express

I am running on VS 2010 Pro  with SP1 Beta and IIS 7.5 Express.  Everything is working fine, but I am trying to access the site from another machine on our intranet and it does not seem to see anything, I simply get a:

> "Oops! This link appears to be broken."

error in Chrome.  Even if I am on the machine and type in:

> 123.45.6.8/SiteName

instead of:

> localhost/SiteName

(which works), I get the error.  Can this be done with IIS 7.5 Express?  Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IIS Express by default only supports local connections - according to a statement by ScottGu, there should be an option to explicitly enable remote connections, however.

See this blog post: [Serving External traffic with WebMatrix](http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx) for how to do this.

Comment: I needed this additional information to get this to work with Visual Studio: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5438322/120955